# binding a command object with ValueConverter

Tags: grails, data-binding

In my Grails 2.3.7 app, I have the following command object

```
class UpdateThresholdsCommand {
    Double threshold_1
    Double threshold_2
}
```

The parameters I'm trying to bind to these properties are formatted currency values, e.g. `threshold_1=$2,459.04&threshold_2=$1,459.04`

I've defined the following implementation of `ValueConverter` to perform this binding

```
class CurrencyStringToDoubleConverter implements ValueConverter {

    FormatService formatService

    @Override
    boolean canConvert(Object value) {
        value instanceof String
    }

    @Override
    Object convert(Object value) {
        formatService.parseCurrency((String) value)
    }

    @Override
    Class<?> getTargetType() {
        Double
    }
}
```

and registered it in `resources.groovy`

```
currencyStringToDoubleConverter(CurrencyStringToDoubleConverter) {
    formatService = ref('formatService')
}
```

But when a request with params such as those shown above is sent to the action, `CurrencyStringToDoubleConverter` is never invoked, so the `threshold_1` and `threshold_2` properties of the command object are null. Why isn't `CurrencyStringToDoubleConverter` being invoked?

Comment: You haven't set `grails.databinding.useSpringBinder` to `true` have you?  The Spring binder does not use `ValueConverter` beans.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown no I'm using the new grails binder

Comment: Mysterious indeed. My first guess was that your converter or service was probably throwing an exception but on second read of your description, "CurrencyStringToDoubleConverter is never invoked" tells me that isn't the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach you describe does work.  See the app at https://github.com/jeffbrown/donalconverter.  Run that app and click the link on the main index page.  The `FormatService` is hardcoded to return `21.12` (see https://github.com/jeffbrown/donalconverter/blob/7a01031deceeea0d857af23f58686b4f1f824e1d/grails-app/services/demo/FormatService.groovy#L7) but the app demonstrates that the converter is being invoked and that the converter is delegating to the service.

You have not shown what your `FormatService` is doing.  It may be that there is something wrong in that code and that is throwing an exception, in which case your command object should have a corresponding binding error associated with it.

It is difficult to say what is going wrong without seeing your code or seeing any relevant errors, but the linked app should demonstrate that the converter is being invoked, at least in that app.

The relevant files in the app:

- [grails-app/conrollers/demo/DemoController.groovy](https://github.com/jeffbrown/donalconverter/blob/master/grails-app/controllers/demo/DemoController.groovy)
- [grails-app/services/demo/FormatService.groovy](https://github.com/jeffbrown/donalconverter/blob/master/grails-app/services/demo/FormatService.groovy)
- [src/groovy/demo/CurrencyStringToDoubleConverter.groovy](https://github.com/jeffbrown/donalconverter/blob/master/src/groovy/demo/CurrencyStringToDoubleConverter.groovy)
- [grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy](https://github.com/jeffbrown/donalconverter/blob/master/grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy)

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I'll investigate further, and if I still suspect there's a big in Grails' databinding, I'll put a demo app on GitHub that isolates the problem

Comment: If you can share a project which demonstrates the problem, then we can fix it.

Comment: There is some relevant detail that you haven't included in the description here because the app I created to try and recreate the problem accounts for all of the details you described, and it works.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone finds their way here, you may have to put this annotation on your converter to give it a higher precedence than the built in Grails converters:

```
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order
import org.springframework.core.Ordered

@Order(value=Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
class DateTimeValueConverter implements ValueConverter  {
    // blah blah
}
```